# Cannot get import gevent to work with my c++ python app

Tags: python-2.7, pip, gevent

I'm trying to get my c++ application, which has python embedded, to import gevent (https://pypi.org/project/gevent/) so I can get some stuff done. Trying for several hours but I just simply can't get it to work. I am using Python 2.7.15 in my app and I am setting python home directory before Py_Initialize to C:\Python27. If I try to import modules like socket or other modules that I've installed with pip, it works well. However, If I try to import gevent, I get an error saying

```
from greenlet import greenlet

ImportError
: 
cannot import name greenlet
```

when I am trying to import gevent. What is really weird to me is, that when I try to import gevent after opening python.exe or basically outside of my c++ application, it works, no problems. I've searched around the net, and it seems like it is supposed to be some name shadowing problem, probably. But I have no idea how to further debug and fix this. Any help would be appreciated.